# How create a field in mongodb schema with pre-defined values, and make the user choose the value with a radio button

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am creating an Schema to create events in the admin dashboard, and i have the following schema:

```
{
 name: String,
 date: Date,
 price: String

}
```

Everything ok, i already create the CRUD, but now i need add a Description field in my schema. And this field is not exactly dynamic, I need it to have 4 pre-defined values:

```
Value 1: Blue
Value 2: Red
Value 3: Yellow
Value 4: Black
```

And on my form I need to bind the user choose [radio button], to an description value.

I have 4 pre-defined values, and i have 4 radio buttons in the form. Example:

```
Radio1 [If the user choose this, the value of description field will be blue]
Radio2 [If the user choose this, the value of description field will be red]
Radio3 [If the user choose this, the value of description field will be yellow]
Radio4 [If the user choose this, the value of description field will be the description black]
```

A bigger example:

If the user create an event with these values:

```
In the name input field, value = 'Super big event'
in the date input field, value = '20/03/2015' (in date format)
in the price input field, value = '50 dollars',
```

in the description radio buttons, he choose radio button with value 1, the output will be:

```
{
name: 'Super big event'
date: '20/03/2015' (in date format)
price: '50 dollars'
description: 'Blue'
}
```

I really appreciate if someone give me a hand here, i didn't find anything with google that could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of schema packages for every framework so I'd first suggest checking before opting for bespoke.

The general pattern you're after involves a separate object for each field.
So, your schema would look like this:

```
Schema = {
    name: {type: String},
    date: {type: Date},
    description: {type: String, possibleValues: ['blue','red','yellow','black']}
}
```

Then, when you validate, you have a function that looks for a possibleValues field. If it exists, then you make sure the submitted value is a member of possibleValues.

Again, no need to build this yourself, but that's the general pattern you'd follow if you wanted to...

Hope it helps!